# How to fix "need to create a seller's account" eBay API?

Tags: python, dictionary, connection, paypal-sandbox, ebay-api

I've created a eBay sandbox account and a paypal sandbox account. When I make a request to AddItem I get an error. I've tried:

```
from ebaysdk.trading import Connection

if __name__ == "__main__":
    api = Connection(config_file=r'C:\Users\username\PycharmProjects\ebay\ebaysdk-python\ebay.yaml', domain='api.sandbox.ebay.com', debug=True)
    request = {
        "Item": {
            "Title": "Professional Mechanical Keyboard",
            "Country": "US",
            "Location": "US",
            "Site": "US",
            "ConditionID": "1000",
            "PaymentMethods": "PayPal",
            "PayPalEmailAddress": "nobody@gmail.com",
            "PrimaryCategory": {"CategoryID": "33963"},
            "Description": "A really nice mechanical keyboard!",
            "ListingDuration": "Days_10",
            "StartPrice": "150",
            "Currency": "USD",
            "ReturnPolicy": {
                "ReturnsAcceptedOption": "ReturnsAccepted",
                "RefundOption": "MoneyBack",
                "ReturnsWithinOption": "Days_30",
                #"Description": "If you are not satisfied, return the keyboard.",
                "ShippingCostPaidByOption": "Buyer"
            },
            "ShippingDetails": {
                "ShippingServiceOptions": {
                    "FreeShipping": "True",
                    "ShippingService": "USPSMedia"
                }
            },
            "DispatchTimeMax": "3"
        }
    }
    api.execute("AddItem", request)
```

error message:
...
ebaysdk.exception.ConnectionError: "AddItem: Class: RequestError, Severity: Error, Code: 120, You need to create a seller's account. Before you can list this item we need some additional information to create a seller's account."

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: I've created a eBay sandbox account: testuser_selleralfa

Comment: Have you checked https://forums.developer.ebay.com/questions/27590/need-a-sellers-account-in-sandbox.html?

Comment: Yes and I've sent in multiple ebay sandbox account and paypal sandbox account linking requests: https://developer.ebay.com/contact-us#help-with-the-ebay-sandbox. I've asked for it to be manually done: https://forums.developer.ebay.com/questions/33995/how-to-associate-the-paypal-account-in-sandbox.html?page=2&pageSize=10&sort=votes

Answer (score 1):

I gave up using the sandbox long ago, and do all the eBay stuff live. The sandbox seems to create more issues than it bypasses.

So the error is "You need to create a seller's account. Before you can list this item we need some additional information to create a seller's account."

Sounds like that is the correct answer. Go into the ebay account linked, list an item for sale, then follow the prompts until it's listed. (Call it "fake item for testing, do not buy" or similar if doing this live.) Whatever is stopping you from listing through the API should also be stopping you from listing through the GUI, and eBay issues are always easier to fix from the front end.

Once you have successfully listed an item on the front end, try running this code again.